# Tag synonym request: [icon] -> [icons]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

[icon](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/icon) and [icons](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/icons) look like they should be the same, there is also [desktop-icons](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/desktop-icons) but that's only been used once so guess that'll die out on its own accord.

Answer (score 2):

### Yes please.

Currently, we have a huge number of questions tagged as both. I don't think we should have both of them and would like it if the mods can just merge them or make icon a synonym of the other.

[icon](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/icon) x 152

[icons](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/icons) x 267

P.S. I have suggested a [synonym for icons](https://askubuntu.com/tags/icons/synonyms). If you have 2500 rep and more than 5 answer votes in [icons](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/icons), feel free to vote on the synonym.